# Sequelize not rendering junction (look up table) values

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize in a Node.js web app. I have a many-to-many relationship and am using a lookup table. The SQL that is generated looks fine, but when I come to use it only the values from the "group" table is displayed.

This is how I've set up the models:

```
//groups
m.User.hasMany(m.Group, { as: 'UserGroups', joinTableName: 'group_users', foreignKey: 'user_id' });
m.Group.hasMany(m.User, { as: 'UserGroups', joinTableName: 'group_users', foreignKey: 'group_id' });
```

This is the raw sql that is being run by sequelize:

```
SELECT `group`.`id`, `group_name`, `created_date`, `description`, `rights`, `join_date` FROM `group`, `group_users` WHERE `group_users`.`user_id`=1 AND `group_users`.`group_id`=`group`.`id`;
```

This is my code:

```
user.getUserGroups({ attributes : [ "group.id", "group_name", "created_date", "description", "rights", "join_date" ] }).success(function (groups) {
  content.groups = groups;
  console.log(groups);
});
```

This is what's being console.log'd out:

```
[ { dataValues:
     { id: 16,
       group_name: 'chris\'s group',
       created_date: Sun Dec 16 2012 17:36:46 GMT+0000 (GMT),
       description: 'test test test',
       rights: 4,
       join_date: Tue Oct 15 2013 13:49:05 GMT+0100 (BST) },
    __options:
     { timestamps: false,
       createdAt: 'createdAt',
       updatedAt: 'updatedAt',
       deletedAt: 'deletedAt',
       touchedAt: 'touchedAt',
       instanceMethods: [Object],
       classMethods: [Object],
       validate: {},
       freezeTableName: true,
       underscored: true,
       syncOnAssociation: true,
       paranoid: false,
       whereCollection: [Object],
       schema: null,
       schemaDelimiter: '',
       language: 'en',
       defaultScope: null,
       scopes: null,
       foreignKeyConstraint: true
       ....
```

This s the raw JSON rendered in the view:

```
 [{"id":16,"group_name":"chris's group","created_date":"2012-12-16T17:36:46.000Z","description":"test test test"},
```

Why can't I see "rights: 4" being rendered as this is definitely being brought back?

Comment: Can you include the code that you are using to render your JSON?

Comment: JOSN.stringify(groups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check that you have defined the `rights` in the sequelize model definition since the `toJSON()` function converts based on defined column names in model definition.